# Is this integral done correctly $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+3}{(x^2+4)^2} dx $

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+3}{(x^2+4)^2} dx = 2 \pi i * res f(x_0)$
Where $x_0$ is residue where $x\geq 0$ for our function $x_0=2i$
$$resf(x_0)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 2i} \frac{d}{dx}[(x-2i)^2 \frac{x^2+3}{(x-2i)^2(x+2i)^2}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2i} \frac{-x^4+x^3(2-4i)+x^2(8i+7)-x(8+12i)+12}{(x+2i)^4}=-1 $$
So then the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+3}{(x^2+4)^2} dx = 2 \pi i *(-1)=-2\pi i$$

Comment: You may want to ask how a real integral gives a pure imaginary value. Uh-oh.

Answer (score 2):

A real integral which gives an imaginary solution? That's sounds strange. Taking $$f(z)=\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2},$$ and the contour $$\Gamma_R=\gamma_R\cup [-R,R],$$ for $R>2$, where $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it},$  for $0\leq t\leq \pi,$ gives us that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{(x^2+4)^2}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\left(\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz-\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz\right).$$
By the residue's theorem gives us, since the unique pole inside the contour is $2i$, open pole of order two,we have that $$\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,z=2i)=2\pi i\frac{d}{dz}\bigg|_{z=2i}\frac{z^2+3}{(z+2i)^2}=2\pi i\frac{2(2iz-3)}{(z+2i)^3}\bigg|_{z=2i}=2\pi i\frac{-14}{-64i}=\frac{7\pi}{16}.$$To conclude we have to check that $$\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz\to 0,$$ as $R\to \infty$. Using the parametrization we get that the integral converts to $$\int_0^\pi\frac{R^2e^{2it}+3}{(R^2e^{2it}+4)^2}Rie^{it}dt,$$ since $|e^{2it}|=1,$ and we can write $$R^2-a=|R^2-a|=||R^2e^{2it}|-|-a||\leq |R^2e^{2it}+a|,$$ for $a=3,4$, we get that $$\left|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz\right|\leq \int_{\gamma_R}\left|\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}\right|dz\leq \pi\frac{R(R^2-3)}{(R^2-4)^2}\to 0,$$ as $R\to\infty$. So we conclude that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{(x^2+4)^2}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\left(\int_{\Gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz-\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{z^2+3}{(z^2+4)^2}dz\right)=\frac{7\pi}{16}.$$

Comment: An answer like this with a downvote. Definitely abandoning this website

Comment: I did not do it, but I have gotten all too many such downvotes. They usually come from people who do not like answering homework questions that lack real effort from the asker (according to the downvoter), or possibly from the asker wanting to learn something other than the answer (e.g., "what did I do wrong?" as opposed to repeating an answer key).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you took the limit as $x\to\infty$ instead of evaluating it at $x=2i$. Also you should note the following from the quotient rule when you have a squared denominator:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{f(x)}{[g(x)]^2}=\dfrac{f'g^2-2fgg'}{g^4}=\dfrac{f'g-2fg'}{g^3},$

canceling out a factor of $g(x)$. This gives a simpler form to calculate later on.

Answer (score 0):

**Real method:Integration by Parts**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+3}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2} d x 
& =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+3}{2 x} d\left(\frac{1}{x^2+4}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{3}{x^2}\right) \frac{1}{x^2+4} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{4}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{3}{16} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+4}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{3}{16}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{x}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{7 \pi}{16} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$